# How can I see the output of my script launch with ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

How can I display in my shell the variable $output of my script launch with my playbook ansible ?

Playbook.yaml :

```
- name: firsttest
  hosts: win
  tasks:
   - name: Ping my Windows vm
     ansible.windows.win_ping:

   - name: Run basic PowerShell script
     ansible.windows.win_powershell:
       script: |
         $output = "Hello World"
         echo $output
```

Comment: How do you normally see the output from ansible playbooks?

Comment: For all modules in Ansible [_you can create variables from the output of an Ansible task with the task keyword `register`_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) and use the [`debug` module – Print statements during execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html).

Comment: If you're debugging, adding the verbose flag may help (`-v`), However, I'm not sure if it will actually show you the output - as the commenter above stated, you can use the keyword `register` and `debug` module to output a value. The examples section on the [`debug` module page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) will probably give you everything you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`register` the results, then `debug`.

```
- name: Run basic PowerShell script
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      $output = "Hello World"
      echo $output
  register: PS_output

- name: Show PS_output
  debug:
    var: PS_output
```